# Find files created during a certain hour of any day

Tags: find, date, timestamps

I understand that it is possible to use `find` to locate files that were created during a specified range of time.  For example, the following should output a list of all the files created (inode change status) at the midnight hour of of January 1st, 2021:

```
find . -newerct "2021-01-01 00:00:00" ! -newerct "2021-01-01 01:00:00"
```

I want to find **all** of the files created during the midnight hour regardless of the date that they were created.  Is there a good way to do this?

```
find . -newerct "ANY-ANY-ANY 00:00:00" ! -newerct "ANY-ANY-ANY 01:00:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `find` (with `-print0`) and `xargs -0` to feed all the filenames to a `stat` command, and filter the results:

```
find . -type f -print0 |\
  xargs -0 -r stat --format="%y %N" |\
  grep -E '^00:' |\
  cut "-d " -f2-
```

Read `man find xargs stat cut`

Comment: Would this be fairly safe to use in conjunction with the `--files-from` argument in `rsync`?

Comment: Probably not. My example reliably preserves spaces and funny characters in filenames, which you would have to quote. The technique is reusable. What is "safe"?

Comment: Thanks, had to make some minor modifications -> `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r stat -c "%y %N" | grep -E ' 00:'` . Leaving for future me.